# Compiling Android app in Eclipse - "keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: android, eclipse, key, keystore, signing

I'm confused with an issue that I'm getting with Eclipse's Android app compilation.
At first, I created an app and a new keystore using the Android Tools -> Export signed Application package.

This created two files: application.apk and application (no file format).

Then I try to compile another app with this "application" file, which I assume is the keystore, because it's only a few kb in size and has cryptic characters inside.

Then I get the error "keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect".
I'm fairly sure I couldn't have forgot the password. Now, is a keystore supposed to be a file without a specified filetype?

I haven't published my app on Google Play yet, it's just a draft, so I assume that I can just try to make a new keystore, and compile both apps again?

Comment: @Nanne has a pretty good answer below, but to answer your last question- yes, you can just create a new keystore if you have not uploaded the APK to Google Play yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you made the keystore, you made an actual file. I'm not sure whatthe "application" is you are refering to, but when you make a keystore, you select a place to save it.

I think, but don't know if it is enforced, the default naming scheme is "xxx.keystore". So look for that file (or create a new one), and use that as keystore.

In your case, the file you use as keystore is probably something else, so it is "tampered with" (aka: not a keystore)

Comment: Okay, it's a bit of a mystery what that file was, but I created a new keystore, in command prompt this time, and I used that to sign both applications in Eclipse. It worked fine.